# How to move hidden fields of a form above other fields

Tags: forms, theming

When a form element is rendered in drupal, some hidden field are added inside the form tag, like bellow:

```
<form action="/example/unsubscribe" method="post" id="exampleform-unsubscribe" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-email">
      <label for="edit-email">E-mail address <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="edit-email" name="email" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Remove me!" class="form-submit" /> <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="formjKkl1KLWJLnv0hM4DSVd8-40boTgBQAzWWhUn44c15Q" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="LB07DqsDXK9idWdOHLxUen7jKxm52JqTyHiR7-pNumA" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="exampleform_unsubscribe" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Is there any way to move all input tag with the "hidden" attribute above the other tags ?
This is the result I am expecting :

```
<form action="/example/unsubscribe" method="post" id="exampleform-unsubscribe" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div>

         <!-- hidden field are moved here - above all field -->
         <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="LB07DqsDXK9idWdOHLxUen7jKxm52JqTyHiR7-pNumA" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="exampleform_unsubscribe" />
    <!-- end of hidden field -->

    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-email">
      <label for="edit-email">E-mail address <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="edit-email" name="email" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Remove me!" class="form-submit" /> <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="formjKkl1KLWJLnv0hM4DSVd8-40boTgBQAzWWhUn44c15Q" />

  </div>
</form>
```

I tried to do that by setting weight for "form_token" and "form_id", but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: How did you set the weight ?

Comment: Why would you ever care about that? These fields are not displayed, and it does not affect what they send, so what problem are you trying to solve, really? If your JS depends on field order, rewrite it now. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble later.

Comment: I am using bootstrap to theme my form. I found when hidden field are located at the end of form there are some bugs in form presentation. but when I move hidden field to above all field and they are located at the begin of form, there is no bug. so I decided to move them above.